# Cant a function be implemented into while loop?

Tags: javascript

```
function start() {
var work = document.getElementById("work").value;
var rest = document.getElementById("rest").value;
var rounds = document.getElementById("rounds");
var timer = document.getElementById("timer");

function countdown() {
    var roundsValue = rounds.value;
    while (roundsValue > 0) {
        var worktime = setInterval(function () {
            timer.value = work + "sec";
            work = work - 1;
            if (work === 0) {
                clearInterval(worktime);
            }
        }, 1000);

        var resttime = setInterval(function(){
            timer.value = rest + "sec";
            rest = rest-1;
            if(rest === 0){
                clearInterval(resttime);
            }
        }, 1000);  

        roundsValue = roundsValue-1;
    }
}
```

}

I am working on my javascript progress right now and I came here with this problem. I want to repeat the same amount of work time and rest time as rounds are but it doesnt work like this and I cant help myself. For example: 8 rounds of 10 seconds of work and then 5seconds of rest. It maybe doesnt work because function cant be implemented into a WHILE loop.

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/shhyq02e/4/

Comment: You can create this function separately and can call the function within the loop.

Comment: You can create functions inside loops, but note they will be recreated at each step, so better create it just once outside the loop. Your code doesn't seems to work because you never call `countdown` function.

Comment: There are many things wrong with your code, you need to call countdown function, roundValue should be an integer for the comparison roundsValue > 0, time events are asynchronous so both the events will coincide

Comment: Set interval functions will repeat themselves after interval, if you are thinking to stop them later, you can't do that because of using local variables, better declare an array outside and place all the reference in the array which you can work with later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a quick fix, may not be the best way to go about it but will get what to do.

http://jsfiddle.net/sahilbatla/shhyq02e/6/

```
function start() {

    var rounds = document.getElementById("rounds");
    var timer = document.getElementById("timer");
    var roundsValue = parseInt(rounds.value);

    (function countdown() {
        var work = document.getElementById("work").value;
        var rest = document.getElementById("rest").value;
        if (roundsValue > 0) {
            var worktime = setInterval(function () {
                timer.value = work + "sec(work)";
                work = work - 1;
                if (work === 0) {
                    clearInterval(worktime);
                    var resttime = setInterval(function() {
                      timer.value = rest + "sec(rest)";
                      rest = rest - 1;
                      if (rest === 0) {
                        clearInterval(resttime);
                        --roundsValue;
                        countdown();
                      }
                    }, 1000); 
                }
            }, 1000);
        }
    })();
}
```